# Richfaces DataTable PDF export

Tags: java, pdf, export, seam

I'm using `Seam 2.2.1` for a little project of mine. I know there is a excel export for `richfaces:dataTable` but is there something like this for PDFs too? I don't really want to write a PDF export with `iText`.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily export the generated HTML to PDF with [Seam PDF](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.CR2/reference/en-US/html/itext.html)

It does use iText internally, but you don't have to write any iText code.

Create a link that takes the same List you are using iterate the RichFaces datatable.

```
<p:table  columns="2" headerRows="1" widthPercentage="95" widths="0.5 0.5" spacingBefore="10">
    <p:cell backgroundColor="#EEEEEE">#{messages['notes.description']}</p:cell>
    <p:cell backgroundColor="#EEEEEE">#{messages['notes.processUserName']}</p:cell>
    <ui:repeat var="note" value="#{yourListHere}">
        <p:cell>#{note.description}</p:cell>
        <p:cell>#{note.processUserName}</p:cell>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:table>
```

Something like this.
Remember to wrap everything inside a

```
<p:document xmlns:p="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pdf">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on using `<rich:dataTable>`, you can try `<p:dataTable>` (primefaces) which has built-in export for PDF. See [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporterHome.jsf)

Otherwise you can use JasperReports for easier, GUI design of your exported PDF.