# Iterating the rendered data of a rich:dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, richfaces

Hey, I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to access the actual rendered rows of a rich:dataTable so as to copy it's content into another destination (e.g. export to an Excel sheet).

The only way we can seemingly get it to work right now is to grab the rendered HTML raw and try to parse our way through it using e.g. [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), but this approach is guaranteed to be ugly and full of hacks.

I was really hoping there would be some neater way to do this, perhaps using a [HtmlDataTable](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/apidoc/org/richfaces/component/html/HtmlDataTable.html) binding to the table, but it seems like all I can get from that is the pre-rendered attributes of the table, which I'm not really interested in.

Any tips or ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Richfaces DataTable PDF export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119144/richfaces-datatable-pdf-export)

Comment: @Joshi: That guy uses Seam, which my project can't/won't do. I also looked into primefaces but simply adding it as a dependency seemed to break the skinning/theme of our app. Still, if I could get primefaces to work seamlessly (np) with the rest of our app then that seems like a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try by copying the datatable with some javascript function into the clipboard and then send it back to the java side where you could then parse it.